# Change height of header in table bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrap table :

```
<table class="table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Id</th>
   <th>ProductName</th>
   <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>bicycle</td>
   <td>5000</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to change the height of **thead ,th** : ***"15px"*** .

Comment: you want height of only `th` or of both `thead` and `th`?

Comment: you can only increase the padding to get the height you want when using bootstrap css.

Comment: @nareeboy : What should i do ?

Comment: posted an answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the default font-size the table head will always be bigger than 15px. You have to reduce the font-size (and the padding) to get your desired height.

```css
thead th {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  padding: 1px !important;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Id</th>
   <th>ProductName</th>
   <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>bicycle</td>
   <td>5000</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I got it  . Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways

Css file or `<style></style>`

```
<style>
    thead th{
       Height: 15px;
    }
</style>


<thead>
    <th style="height: 15px"></th>
<thead>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your html file where you have the bootstrap cdn link or the local directory path, after the boostrap link add the path to you css file. Always add your css file link after the bootsrap link so it overwrites any of the bootstrap css.

```
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourpathname.css">
```

then go to your css file and add: You would have to add something greater than 15 pixels.

```
 th {
        height: 50px;
    }
```

Comment: Why  i can not add the height  < 15 pixels ? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/24163/)

Comment: This is my hypothesis, do not take my work for it. Sometimes in bootstrap certain elements have set padding, margin, and height that may exceed what you want your height to be.Therefore because yours is smaller compared to that of bootstrap it would not offset them and show the heigh you want yours to be. This is why you would want something greater in this case in order for yours to show. For example, There is also a case where the bootstrap navbar would overlay your content, and you would have to add a padding of an extra 70 px, because the height of the navbar by default is 50px.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
   table th, table thread {
    height: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to overwrite the css from bootstrap, so add a class to the table e.g class="my-table".

```
  .my-table thead th {
    padding: 10px 0 5px 0 !important;
  }
```

I am just picking out numbers, but you will need to make this equal by changing the numbers I have added.

The main thing is to add the !important text after the css. This will overwrite the bootstrap css. Also take note. when writing css: padding: 10px 0 5px 0, the first number is padding-top, the 2nd number padding-right, third number is padding-bottom and the forth number is padding-left.